# Adding "predict" outcome to the initial dataframe

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am a a bit lost on how can I append the predicted probabilities to a new column in the original dataset 'advertising' (I know that there should be a test/validation, but this is an exercise and we are allowed to do it not splitting the data.

```
advertising <- read.csv('C:/Users/matpo/Desktop/advertising_1.csv', stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
LogMod <- glm(Clicked.on.Ad ~ Daily.Time.Spent.on.Site + Age + Area.Income, data=advertising, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(LogMod)
predicted <- predict(LogMod, advertising, type="response") 
predicted [1:5]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `advertising$predicted <- predicted`.

Comment: Check out `broom::augment` as well. The package has quite a number of cool function to easily export fitted values and model outputs. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html